# Bounding distance between random variables.

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, measure-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{A}, P)$ be a probability space and $\mathcal{H}$ a real Hilbert space. Consider two $\mathcal{H}$-valued random variables, $X:\Omega\to\mathcal{H}$ and $Y:\Omega\to\mathcal{H}$, which are dependent. Furthermore, let's assume that $\forall \omega\in\Omega$, $X(\omega)\in C\subset \mathcal{H}$ and $Y(\omega)\in C\subset \mathcal{H}$ where $C$ is a ball of radius $\frac{r}{2}$ centered at the origin. Can we say the following,

$$\|X-Y\|^2\leq r^2$$

Of course, if we had two vectors $x$ and $y$ in $C$ then we can bound the norm $\|x-y\|$ by the diameter of $C$. However, I am naive to probability theory and my peer is telling me that I cannot write $\|X-Y\|^2\leq r^2$ because $X$ and $Y$ are functions, not vectors in $\mathcal{H}$. This doesn't make sense to me because they are pointwise (i.e. for all $\omega\in\Omega$) in $C$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue of unclear notation, and if you had said more precisely what your notation means the problem might not have arisen.  You are both right: $\|X-Y\|$ is a function on $\Omega$, and the inequality $\|X(\omega)-Y(\omega)\|^2\le r^2$ holds for all $\omega$.  You meant $\|X-Y\|$ in the pointwse sense, and your peer understood you to mean it was some kind of norm on a space of Hilbert space-valued functions of $\Omega$. Without further explanation both interpretations are reasonable.

You might have said something like $P(\|X-Y\|^2\le r^2)=1$, or even "the random variable $\|X-Y\|$ obeys $P(\|X-Y\|^2\le r^2)=1$" or (more tersely), "$\|X-Y\|\le r^2$ holds pointwise in $\omega$".

There is no absolute truth about mathematical notations: they are just tools we use to help convey our ideas.  If your notations are misunderstood it is just like your words being misunderstood; if you find out you have been misunderstood, you fix the problem by rewording.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me. Ok, so $\|X-Y\|$ is a function from $\Omega\to\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. Still, this function is bounded by $r$ no? There is no event $\omega$ for which $X$ or $Y$ are not in the set $C$ so it feels like I should be able to say the function $\|X-Y\|\leq r$.

Comment: Of course your vector-valued function of $\omega$ is bounded, and your notation $\|X-Y\|$ is still a little bit unclear.  I have edited my answer in response to your comment.